# Using less Random Access Memory

Tags: data-compression

Suppose you were to compress data before it was sent to Random Access Memory. Wouldn't you technically be using less R.A.M?

Comment: There are several problems with this. For example, it would be very slow. Another problem is that data is often read in very small chunks, which interferes with compression.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  When you phrase the question that way, it makes me think you believe/suspect there is some reason why that might not be true.  Can you say any more about where that's coming from?  I encourage you to edit the question to provide more context about why you're asking and what the context/motivation is.  This helps get you better answers and so is in your interest.